# Powershell - Writing expression to get data from variable

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to simply insert a column into a csv using similar Add-Member logic, however I am unsure if I'm supposed to be specifying an -InputObject, which I believe is for copying properties from one object to another.

I'm calling a Graph API endpoint with this code:

`$ActivationReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $activationsUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv`

I'd like to simply grab the column from this array with the header of "Last Activated Date' and simply do an Add-Member into this code below. This properly inserts extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber as a new column, however I am unsure how to insert `Last Activated Date` from the `$ActivationReport` array...

```
    $CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -Value $CurrentEmpNumber
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastActivatedDate -Value @{Label="LastActivatedDate";Expression={$_.'Last Activated Date'}},'Last Activated Date'
}
```

Is it as simple as specifying an InputObject when doing an `Add-Member`? Unsure if my expression is wrong, but not sure how to create the link between this logic and `$ActivationReport`

Here is the full code:

````
$clientID = "hidden"
$tenantID = "hidden.onmicrosoft.com"
$ClientSecret = "hidden"
$LogPath = "$env:TEMP"
$From = "hidden@domain.com"
$To = "hidden@domain.com"
$ReportPath = "$env:TEMP"
$sendEmail=$true

#Region GetToken
Write-Output "Acquiring Graph API Token..."
try {
    $body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
    $oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
    $headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error getting Graph Token."
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    EXIT
}
# endregion GetToken

$activeUserDetailURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization"

$organizationName = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $activeUserDetailURI -Headers $headerParams -ErrorAction STOP).Value.DisplayName

# Force TLS 1.2
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$fileSuffix = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy")

#Region Paths
#..........................................................
#If ReportPath if blank, create the default path
if (!$ReportPath)
{
    $ReportPath = "$LogPath\Report"
    #$ReportPath = "$script_root\Report"
}

#If ReportPath does not exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path $ReportPath))
{
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $ReportPath | Out-Null
}

#Define report CSV file
$ReportFileNameCSV = "ActiveUserLicenseDetail_$fileSuffix.csv"
$ReportFileNameHTML = "ActiveUserLicenseCount_$fileSuffix.HTML"
$ReportCSV = "$LogPath\$ReportFileNameCSV"
$ReportHTML = "$LogPath\$ReportFileNameHTML"

#If LogPath if blank, create the default path
if (!$LogPath)
{
    $LogPath = "$ReportPath\Log"
}

#If ReportPath does not exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path $LogPath))
{
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LogPath | Out-Null
}

#Define Log file
$LogFile = "$LogPath\Log_$fileSuffix.log"

#EndRegion Paths

#Region MailParamCheck
#..........................................................
$isAllGood = $true

if ($sendEmail -eq $true)
{
    if (!$From)
    {
        Write-Output "A valid sender email address is not specified."
        $isAllGood = $false
    }

    if (!$To)
    {
        Write-Output "No recipient specified."
        $isAllGood = $false
    }
}

if ($isAllGood -eq $false)
{
    Write-Output "Exiting Script."
    EXIT
}
#..........................................................
#EndRegion MailParamCheck

if ($To)
{
    $toAddressJSON = @()
    $To | ForEach-Object {$toAddressJSON += @{EmailAddress = @{Address = $_}}}
}

Write-Output "Querying Graph API..."

#some other stuff - update this comment
$graphApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')"
$activationsUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail"

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$select=userPrincipalName,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber"

$O365Report = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphApiUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv

Write-Output "Querying Graph API for Office activations..."

$ActivationReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $activationsUri -Headers $headerParams | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Get-DistributionGroupMember $DL | Select @{Label="DL";Expression={$DL}},@{Label="User";Expression={$_.Name}},primarySmtpAddress 

# If the result is more than 999, we need to read the @odata.nextLink to show more than one side of users
$UserDetails = while (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri)) {
    # API Call
    $apiCall = try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headerParams -Uri $uri -Method Get
    }
    catch {
        $errorMessage = $_.ErrorDetails.Message | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    $uri = $null
    if ($apiCall) {
        # Check if any data is left
        $uri = $apiCall.'@odata.nextLink'
        $apiCall
    }
}

Write-Output "Matching UPN to employeeNumber..."

$O365ReportWithActivation = ForEach ($user in $O365Report) {
    $user | Select userPrincipalName,
        # Look up the value of activated date using $ActivationReport + add as property
        @{l='LastActivatedDate';e={
          $ActivationReport | 
            Where-Object {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $user.'User Principal Name'} | 
            select -ExpandProperty 'Last Activated Date'
        }},
        @{l='extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber';e={$UserDetails.value | Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}}
}

$O365Report | Export-Csv $ReportCSV -NoTypeInformation
Write-Output "Report saved to $ReportCSV."

#If sendEmail is not equal to TRUE, exit here.
if ($sendEmail -ne $true) {EXIT}
#Else, continue with email report

#convert attachment to base 64 encoded format
Write-Output "Converting Report to Base 64 for use as email attachment."
$fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((get-content $ReportCSV -Raw))
$base64_csv = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)

#Outlook API
Write-Output "Acquire Token to send email, in case our previous token times out."

try {
    $outlookMailApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($From)/sendmail"
    $body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
    $oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body -ErrorAction STOP
    $headerParams = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error getting email Token."
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    EXIT
}

Write-Output "Creating Report."

$licenseProps = @{
    Exchange = ($O365Report | Where-Object {$_."Has Exchange License" -eq $true}).count
    Sharepoint = ($O365Report | Where-Object {$_."Has Sharepoint License" -eq $true}).count
    OneDrive = ($O365Report | Where-Object {$_."Has OneDrive License" -eq $true}).count
    Teams = ($O365Report | Where-Object {$_."Has Teams License" -eq $true}).count
}

$license = New-Object psobject -Property $licenseProps

#message
$messageSubject = "[$($organizationName)] M365 Assigned Licenses Report : " + (Get-Date -format F)

$cssString = @'
<style type="text/css">
.tftable {table-layout:fixed;width: 40%;font-family:"Segoe UI";font-size:12px;color:#333333;border-width: 1px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {width: 30%;font-size:12px;background-color:#acc8cc;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:left;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#d4e3e5;}
.tftable td {width: 10%font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;}
.tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
</style>
'@

$messageBody = '<html>'
$messageBody += "<head><title>$($messageSubject)</title>"
$messageBody += '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 />'
$messageBody += $cssString
$messageBody += '</head><body>'
$messageBody += '<p><font face="Segoe UI"><h3>Summary of Microsoft 365 Assigned Licenses Count</h3></font></p>'
$messageBody += '<table class="tftable">'
$messageBody += '<tr><th>Exchange</th><td>'+("{0:n0}" -f $license.Exchange)+'</td></tr>'
$messageBody += '<tr><th>SharePoint</th><td>'+("{0:n0}" -f $license.Sharepoint)+'</td></tr>'
$messageBody += '<tr><th>OneDrive</th><td>'+("{0:n0}" -f $license.OneDrive)+'</td></tr>'
$messageBody += '<tr><th>Teams</th><td>'+("{0:n0}" -f $license.Teams)+'</td></tr>'
$messageBody += '</table><hr />'
$messageBody += '<p><font face="Segoe UI"><h3>End of Report<h3></font></p>'
$messageBody += '<p><font size="2" face="Segoe UI">'

$messageBody += '</body>'
$messageBody += '</html>'
$messageBody | out-file $ReportHTML

#Prepare mailbody JSON
$mailBody = @{
    Message = @{
        Subject = $messageSubject
        Body = @{
            ContentType = "HTML"
            Content = $messageBody
            #Content = "ATTACHED"
        }
        ToRecipients = @(
            $ToAddressJSON
        )
        Attachments = @(
            @{
                "@odata.type" = "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment"
                Name = "$($ReportFileNameCSV)"
                ContentType = "multipart/mixed"
                ContentBytes = $base64_csv
            }
        )
    }
    SaveToSentItems = $false
}
$mailBody = $mailBody | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 4

#send email
Write-Output "Send Email Report from $From"
try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $outlookMailApiUri -Body $mailbody -Headers $headerParams -ContentType application/json -ErrorAction STOP
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error sending email."
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    EXIT
}```
````

Comment: Currently performing a test with ```$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastActivatedDate -Value @{Label="LastActivatedDate";Expression={$ActivationReport.'Last Activated Date'}},'Last Activated Date'```

Comment: This resulted in a column being inserted and each row indicates ```System.Object[]
```

Comment: Does this mean the issue is resolved?

Comment: No - I'm not sure how to solve this and display the correct values, rather than System.Object.  Trying again with $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastActivatedDate -Value ($ActivationReport.'Last Activated Date' | Out-String).Trim() @lit

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to merge data from another report, or just rename a property/column?

Otherwise, I think you'll have to add the rest of your script to see what is going on.

[Edit]

To quickly add a column with a lookup value, I prefer to use `select-object` like so:

```
$O365ReportWithActivation = ForEach ($user in $O365Report) {
    $user | Select *,
        # Look up the value of activated date using $ActivationReport + add as property
        @{l='LastActivatedDate';e={
          $ActivationReport | 
            Where-Object {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $user.'User Principal Name'} | 
            select -ExpandProperty 'Last Activated Date'
        }},
        @{l='extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber';e={$CurrentEmpNumber}}
}
```

Hopefully I put the property names in the right places, I think it's like this? `$ActivationReport.userPrincipalName` and `$O365Report.'User Principal Name'`

Comment: I'm trying to merge data from another report - I just want to take the values from 'Last Activated Date' and insert as a new column. The code is currently doing this with the users endpoint and inserting a column for employeeNumber: ```$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$select=userPrincipalName,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber"```

Comment: @jpbcx43 I've added the way I do that. It's the same as what you were already doing for $CurrentEmpNumber - you have to iterate through activation report to get the one that matches. I like to do it within the `expression={}` clause, but it's just preference.

Comment: Great! I will run this and see what it exports to csv! It's running now ;-) I will report back. Greatly appreciate your help! Been bashing my head into the wall for days. I am wondering if we need to ExpandProperty for ```'Last Activated Date'``` or for ```extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber``` similar to what I was doing before when matching.....i'll let it rip for now.

Comment: Question - if I am replacing my code with yours above, how do we know what $CurrentEmpNumber is, if that logic is commented out? Simple as just inserting ```$CurrentEmpNumber = $UserDetails.value``` before your logic starts?

Comment: oh yeah - just replace `$CurrentEmpNumber` in my code with everything after the `=` in yours: `$UserDetails.value |
        Where-Object userPrincipalName -eq $_.'User Principal Name' |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Hmm it's been running for a while now - it usually takes about 20 minutes to run (8,000 or so accounts in our tenant) perhaps ```$user | Select *``` is a bit excessive?

Comment: I just updated the code to see if you can pick out something that's causing it to not want to finish. Thanks mate @user19702

Comment: @jpbcx43 definitely, depending on how large the data/object lists are, selecting only the properties you need may do better. I can't be sure what your object types are, but they may have some properties that have to get calculated. `ADPrincipal` objects give me this trouble for example.

Comment: The code you have looks like it would work fine. It may be worthwhile to add a `Write-Progress` line inside the foreach loop like so: `Write-Progress -Activity 'adding properties' -Status "user: $($user.userPrincipalName)" -PercentComplete ([math]::Round(($O365Report.IndexOf($user) / $O365Report.Count)*100,0))` and see if it's actually processing users / how long each user takes.

Comment: If any of `$O365report`/`$UserDetails`/`$ActivationReport` are gigantic, it may be worthwhile to convert them to a hash table for quicker lookups. It's a little complicated for this question though.